# Overwrite methods but keep decorator (python)

Tags: python, methods, overwrite, prefect

I got a Class and a Subclass and want to inherit a method with the decorator *@task* from framework *prefect.io*.

Code Sample:

**Class**

```
@task
def test1(self):
     pass
```

**Subclass**

```
def test2(self):
     print("succeed")
```

But now the method *test2* doesn´t have the decorator *@task* anymore. I can´t declarate *@task* in the Subclass. Is it possbile that i can overwrite the method but keep *@task* ?

Comment: Why not just import task into the scope such that the subclass can decorate its method with?

Comment: "I can´t declarate @task in the Subclass." why can't you?

Comment: "Is it possbile that i can overwrite the method but keep @task" this isn't possible, you will ultimately have to decorate the resulting method again *somehow*.

Comment: ok @juanpa.arrivillaga,  thanks for your answer, that it´s not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually recommend something like

```
class Base:
    @task
    def test1(self):
        return self.test1_impl()

    def test1_impl(self):
        ...


class Child:
    def test1_impl(self):
        ...
```

Now `Child`'s job isn't to override the decorated function, but rather the undecorated function *used by* the inherited decorated function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not import task again?

```
from prefect import task
```

Comment: because DRY? if you need both tasks and both have the same arguments, you shouldn't need to maintain updates manually